# Converting XML to text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, text

While trying to convert XML to text, I came across this problem. I'm using xstl and I'm wondering how can I convert few postions from one variable to show on txt. It's currently working for one record.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:template match="/">

    
    <xsl:text>CaseId;Numer faktury;Data sprzedaży;Data wystawienia;Sprzedawca nazwa;Sprzedawca kod pocztowy;Sprzedawca miastoSprzedawca adres;Sprzedawca NIP;Konto bankowe;Forma płatności;Pozycje faktury;Kwota netto;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>


    <xsl:for-each select="AMODCases/AMODCase">
        
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='CaseId']" /><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Numer faktury']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Data sprzedaży']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Data wystawienia']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Sprzedawca nazwa']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Sprzedawca kod pocztowy']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Sprzedawca miasto']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Sprzedawca adres']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Sprzedawca NIP']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Konto bankowe']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name='Forma płatności']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./substring[@Name='Pozycje faktury']"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(./Property[@Name='Kwota netto']/@DBValue,',','.')" /><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                
        

        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each> 

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example input:

```
    <Property Name="CaseId" Type="Int32" >714</Property>
    <Property Name="Numer faktury" Type="Int32" >22-FVI/06/WRC </Property>
    <Property Name="Data sprzedaży" Type="DateTime" >2022-06-02</Property>
    <Property Name="Data wystawienia" Type="DateTime" >2022-06-02</Property>
    <Property Name="Sprzedawca nazwa" Type="Varchar" >ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ</Property>
    <Property Name="Sprzedawca kod pocztowy" Type="Varchar" >31-574</Property>
    <Property Name="Sprzedawca miasto" Type="Varchar" >Kraków</Property>
    <Property Name="Sprzedawca adres" Type="Varchar" >ul. Ciepłownicza</Property>
    <Property Name="Sprzedawca NIP" Type="INT32" >945</Property>
    <Property Name="Konto bankowe" Type="Int32" >1310902</Property>
    <Property Name="Forma płatności" Type="Varchar" >Przelew na 
 rachunek bankowy</Property>
    <Property Name="Pozycje faktury" Type="List`1" ></Property>
    <Property Name="Kwota netto" Type="Int32" >535</Property>
```

Output:

```
CaseId;Numer faktury;Data sprzedaży;Data wystawienia;Sprzedawca nazwa;Sprzedawca kod pocztowy;Sprzedawca miastoSprzedawca adres;Sprzedawca NIP;Konto bankowe;Forma płatności;Pozycje faktury;Kwota netto;
714;22-FVI/06/WRC;2022-06-02;2022-06-02;ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ;31-574;Kraków;ul. Ciepłownicza;945;1310902;Przelew na rachunek bankowy;;;
```

Expected output:

```
CaseId;Numer faktury;Data sprzedaży;Data wystawienia;Sprzedawca nazwa;Sprzedawca kod pocztowy;Sprzedawca miastoSprzedawca adres;Sprzedawca NIP;Konto bankowe;Forma płatności;Pozycje faktury;Kwota netto;
714;22-FVI/06/WRC;2022-06-02;2022-06-02;ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ;31-574;Kraków;ul. Ciepłownicza;945;1310902;Przelew na rachunek bankowy;1;535;
```

The output should be able to contain from multiple rows, also i doesn't show the two last rows on the text file generated.

Any link, or example will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of the input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: Your Expected output does not use the data of the Example input. And I doubt that your header-line (starting with `CaseId;Numer faktury;`) should be repeated?

Comment: The example is neither minimal nor reproducible (the input has no elements named `AMODCases` or `AMODCase`. And it's not clear what version your processor supports: your stylesheet declares `version="2.0"` - but it also declares a `msxsl` namespace, which makes very little sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `Property` of `Kwota netto` has no attribute named `DBValue`. To get the expected value of `535` you need to change your:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(./Property[@Name='Kwota netto']/@DBValue,',','.')" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Kwota netto']" />
```

I don't know where the expected value of `1` for the `Property` of `Pozycje faktury` is supposed to come from, so I cannot help you there.

And I don't know what you mean by:

> The output should be able to contain from multiple rows